# Elementary OS on Macbook won't display wifi settings. How do i fix?

Tags: wifi, macbook

[image: Screenshot]

Hello. I am trying to use elementary on my macbook pro, but i won't display wifi unless i plug in usb wifi dongle. So, the drivers are missing i suppose. I had this issue before and it was solved with a system update. Now how can i fix and enjoy elementary os?

Comment: works on Macbook Pro 13" mid 2009, thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following steps fixes the problem.

- Removing bcmwl-kernel-source package, then reboot:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
  sudo reboot
  ```
- Installing new broadcom firmware:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
  ```
- Reload package.

  ```
  sudo modprobe -r b43
  sudo modprobe b43
  ```

Source: http://www.linuxlinx.com/2016/08/fix-no-wireless-on-macbook-after.html

Comment: Following the above steps works for me on a macbook pro 2009.

Comment: these instructions still work on a 2009 MBP in Elementary OS 5.0 as of May 2019

Comment: Same issue, but when I tried this with Elementary 5.1 (on an Air 2013) it said `Package bcmwl-kernel-source is not installed, so not removed`??

Comment: This did not work for me and my 15" Macbook Pro 2013.
I had a bad ethernet cord, so solving this took 10x as long. Running the Updates in AppCenter seems to be working. Click on the Broadcom Driver. Yes it worked after reboot. I have WiFi icon showing. Get Wired Connection and Run the Updates FIRST. Then install the bcmwl-kernel-source Drivers (you have to click on them in AppCenter). For the 2013 Macbook Pro, the secret is getting the Thunderbolt to RJ45 (Ethernet) dongle. Even after I connected it, I had no ethernet device name after [ip a].
I had to test on another machine to find out my et

Comment: Worked for me on Mid-2012 MacBook Pro.