# What’s the reason for the missing WiFi drivers on install media?

Tags: wifi, networking, drivers, release-hera

I’m currently trying to use the latest installation media, released yesterday for elementary (version 5.1). Currently it’s showing no signs of support (drivers) for WiFi network adapters. Are they included in the installation media and if so what ones are compatible please?

Comment: did you by any chance check the box for installing third party drivers during the install process?

Answer (score 0):

For your wifi card to work, you must check a case during the installation of Elementary OS (this is very often the case for many LINUX distribution)

*Before the installation* in the window **Update and other software** you need check this option :

**Install third-party software for graphics Wi-Fi Hardware and additional media formats**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do it either at least on my MacBook Pro Retina.

Comment: I checked the Third party installation service but still the wifi doesn't works, it always shows `Wireless disconnected` in the Network, as well as `No Access Points Available` though the Wireless button at the right is ON. Another issue is that an error continuously pops up, `Failed to Fetch Updates` in details, it shows `http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease is not yet available

Comment: @screenglow I think this link help you : https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11783/elementary-os-on-macbook-wont-display-wifi-settings-how-do-i-fix