# MacBook Air WiFi antenna not detected on Elementary OS 5.1

Tags: wifi, release-hera, drivers, macbook

When trying Elementary OS 5.1 on a 2013 MacBook Air 13 (6,2) from a USB stick, everything seems to work, except for WiFi. The WiFi hardware does not show up at all.

There is [a very similar question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11783/elementary-os-on-macbook-wont-display-wifi-settings-how-do-i-fix) already, and it has an answer, but for a different version of Elementary OS (5.0). That solution removes the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package and installs `firmware-b43-installer`, but 5.1 does not include `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: try installing 'broadcom-sta-dkms' instead.

Comment: I don't know what to *remove* though. I haven't tried *installing* anything yet.

Comment: have you installed eOS on the USB stick with the same machine?

Comment: Nope. I created the USB stick using an older version of Ubuntu, then replaced that Ubuntu with eOS, all on an old Toshiba Satellite. When I tried the USB stick with my MacBook Air, it didn't detect the WiFi antenna.

Comment: I just remembered that the WiFi antenna wasn't detected on the Toshiba either, but I plugged in an external USB antenna, and that worked fine.

Comment: Proprietary WiFi driver is removed if the device is not available on the installed machine once eOS is installed. So your installation may not have bcmwl-kernel-source driver. I would just try installing broadcom-sta-dkms.

Comment: or b43 maybe. Found installation log on Debian site.
[https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookAir/6-2#WiFi]

Comment: Thank you, guys. Much appreciated. I'll follow up on your suggestions.