# No wifi on fresh Odin install

Tags: wifi, networking, macbook, release-odin

After installing Elementary OS 6 Odin on a macbook pro 13" late 2011 , network manager only shows wired network, no wifi.

Output lspci:
`03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 02)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally make it work,

uninstall all drivers for a fresh install

```
sudo apt-get purge b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43-lpphy-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer bcmwl*
```

re install only this ones

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```

after that remove or comment the blacklisted kernel module `bcm43xx` in the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. You can do it manually or with this command

```
keyword='blacklist bcm43xx'; sudo sed -i "/^$keyword/ c#$keyword" blacklist.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

After you connect to internet using your smartphone and USB cable, do this

```
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

More details here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: This do not work for me. i think bcmwl-kernel-source do not include driver for BCM4331

Comment: It's on the list of supported cards you can find following the link in my answer. I had this issue with my previous laptop, with a different Broadcom card though, and it always worked. I'm sorry if it doesn't for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source, it looks like you might try the b43 driver.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Specifically, [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11783/elementary-os-on-macbook-wont-display-wifi-settings-how-do-i-fix) suggests following commands:

Remove bcmwl-kernel-source package, then reboot.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo reboot
```

Install b43 broadcom firmware.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reload package.

```
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

Comment: this, didnt work, but i found the solution